# Any message browsing possible in Azure Service bus

Tags: azureservicebus

Is there any way to message browse in Azure Service bus for .net core similar to .net framework's servicebus.messaging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-browsing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Service Bus Explorer. The tool does a lot.

https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer

Documentation

https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/blob/develop/docs/documentation.md

**EDIT**

See the following samples that show you to use the API(s).

https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus

[Message Browsing](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/MessageBrowse) is probably what you are after.

> Message Browsing - MessageBrowse shows how to enumerate all messages
>   residing in a Queue or Subscription without receiving or locking them.
>   This method also allows finding deferred and scheduled messages.

Comment: Thanks for reply .....but is it possible if I can do this through apis ...basically querying service bus and retrieving all current messages residing in  it

Comment: I edited my answer. You should update your question so that its clear you were looking for API guidance. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Message browsing programmatically is identical with both clients, the .NET Framework [`WindowsAzure.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/windowsazure.servicebus) () and the new .NET Standard [`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.azure.servicebus) client.

[Browsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-browsing) is possible in receive mode [`PeekLock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.receivemode?view=azure-dotnet). Using either `QueueClient` or `SubscriptionClient` you can peek messages.

Note that you can peek messages by count, i.e. how many messages to peek, but not by their [status](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/95). Additionally, you can peek messages one at a time by their [`SequenceNumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.peekasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueClient_PeekAsync_System_Int64_).